# ipv6 not working - Port 9001/9030 not reachable - but Port 22 is

Tags: relays, ipv6

I am currently trying to get my Relay ipv6 ready.
However the Port Tor Runs on seems inaccessible.
Couldn't identify an issue with Port forwarding (ipv4 works; SSH on ipv6 works as well).

The Ping-Check specified at https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorRelayGuide#IPv6 worked for all but 001:678:558:1000::244.
Also don't have an explanation for that, since ipv6 Pings seem to work fine (eg. Google works on ipv6), but if I enter the address in an online Pingtest (Webpage that let you Ping targets) they report it as online.

The Relay:
https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/45D8C1EEFF044043AA6806C4B9130F8F189EF316

Comment: Are you sure that's your IPv6 address? (I assumed the first bit was a typo and was meant to be 2001) It is on a completely different AS to the IPv4 address in that relay report. It also hasn't got port 22 open.

Comment: My ipv6 address is 2002:d5b2:1a3f:0:c28e:44d0:436d:d315. The "2001:678..." (you were right about typo) is one specified to ping by Tor to check if your ipv6 works. (It didn't respond to pings by me, but apparently it responds if submitted here: https://subnetonline.com/pages/ipv6-network-tools/online-ipv6-ping.php)

Comment: That's an [old deprecated 6to4 address](https://ip.addr.space/2002:d5b2:1a3f:0:c28e:44d0:436d:d315), with the 6to4 relay apparently provided [by your ISP](https://ip.addr.space/213.178.26.63). These are [not reliable](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7526) and you should contact your ISP about making native IPv6 service work.

Comment: I see, that might be the Problem. I will call them on Monday. I couldn't get what my Router called "native" ipv6 to work and this was the only option which allowed me to use ipv6 without submitting additional credentials (which I don't have)

Comment: @ValentinMetz did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Seems to be that my ISP only offers this outdated 6to4. As no native ipv6 is provided, I switched ipv6 off.